# How to apply True/False operators in expressions

Tags: lambda-calculus

My class on lambda calculus never defined True/False operators and uses them in ways I can't reverse-engineer. Here are two examples:

Question 1. What does the following expression evaluate to?

`(tru 2 3) (add 4) 2`

Answers:

1. 2
2. 3
3. 4
4. 6
5. 8
6. 10

My attempt: `(tru 2 3)` returns the first term which is 2. Then you add 4 twice which gives 10 total. So 6) is the answer.

Question 2. What does the following expression evaluate to?

`fls succ plus 2 3`

Answers:

1. 2
2. 3
3. 4
4. 5
5. 6

My attempt: `plus 2 3` returns 5. `succ 5` returns 6. And false doesn't do anything. So the answer is 5).

I'm less worried about the answer to these questions and would rather understand how to use `tru fls` in any expression. I just don't see how they can be used with numbers.

Answer (score 0):

```
tru = λt. λf. t

tru v w
= (λt.λf.t) v w by definition
−→ (λf. v) w reducing the underlined redex
−→ v reducing the underlined redex
```

```
fls = λt. λf. f

fls v w
= (λt.λf.f) v w by definition
−→ (λf. f) w reducing the underlined redex
−→ w reducing the underlined redex
```

[source (page 5)](https://www.seas.upenn.edu/%7Ecis500/cis500-f06/lectures/0925-2x3.pdf)

Comment: So True returns the 1st term while False returns the 2nd term? But then how do you process `fls 6` since there is only one term?